# Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "xxx"

Tags: qt, qml, alias

The following simple QML component is not giving me the expected results:

```
// Square.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    property alias side: width
    height: width
}
```

The error I get is `Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "width"`
I don't understand why it cannot find `width` since I know it is within the rectangle. Adding it explicitly and giving it a value doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: To the downvoter, I'd love to know what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is right inside the error, if you read it closely enough:

```
Invalid alias reference. Unable to find **id** "width"
```

It's expecting `width` to be the id of a component in the current scope. There is no such id, only a *property*.

The solution is simple:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property alias side: root.width
    height: width
}
```

Comment: Even if it is self-answered question, this is a really good answer that may help to figure out problem.